# Statistically identical lm() and t.test() yield marginally different effect sizes

Tags: r, statistics, regression, lm

I'm encountering an unexpected lack of correspondence between the estimated effects of an unpaired `t.test()` and `lm()` in base R's stats. While an independent-samples t-test correctly yields `t = 0` and a manual calculation of OLS slope also outputs an estimate of 0, `lm()` gives a near-zero approximation (specifically, `-3.239e-14`).

This pattern holds across machines and OS (Mac and Windows) versions as tested by my coworkers. Would anyone be able to explain the discrepancy? The most similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59115035/lm-and-t-testvar-equal-true-differ-on-one-machine-but-not-on-another-poss) does not seem to apply here.

```r
# Populating an example dataframe
id <- rep(1, 16)
dose <- rep(c(rep("Low", 4), rep("High", 4)), 2)
domain <- c(rep("Domain1", 8), rep("Domain2", 8))
dv <- c(100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 50, 0)

df <- data.frame(id, dose, domain, dv)
```

```r
library(dplyr) ## needed for %>% and filter()
# Independent-samples t-test
t.test(dv ~ dose,
       data = filter(df, domain == "Domain1") %>% droplevels(), 
       paired = F)

# data:  dv by dose
# t = 0, df = 6, p-value = 1
```

```r
# Linear regression of factor IV and numeric DV 
summary(lm(as.numeric(dv) ~ as.factor(dose), 
           data = filter(df, domain == "Domain1")))

# Coefficients:
#                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
# (Intercept)         7.500e+01  2.500e+01       3    0.024 *
# as.factor(dose)Low -3.239e-14  3.536e+01       0    1.000
```

```r
# Manual calculation of OLS slope
X <- model.matrix(dv ~ dose, data = filter(df, domain == "Domain2"))
y <- with(filter(df, domain == "Domain1"), dv)
R <- t(X) %*% X
solve(R) %*% t(X) %*% y

#             [,1]
# (Intercept)   75
# doseLow        0
```

Comment: Different algorithms, different rounding, different precision. With 16,000 data points, `-3.239e-14` is close enough to 0 to be treated as 0. With 16 data points, even more so.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the quick response! But is there a way to override the default behavior of the underlying algorithm to make the zero-value output display consistent across statistical tests?

Comment: You can use `round()` on the results. It's not the underlying algorithm you want to adjust, it's the print methods. [Here's a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15732738/903061) (without a more satisfying answer). If you use the `broom` package and put the results in a tibble, they may print more to your liking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The t-statistic is *exactly* zero for `t.test()` (assign the results to `tt` and try `tt$statistic == 0`), while after assigning the results of `summary()` to `ss` we get

```r
ss$coefficients["as.factor(dose)Low", "Estimate"]
[1] -3.014578e-14
```

(extracting the values and printing them avoids any rounding/formatting that might be done in the `print()` methods for these objects).

As discussed in the comments, this discrepancy is a more-or-less unavoidable aspect of floating point imprecision, and the fact that the two functions do mathematically equivalent calculations using very different numerical algorithms. (In hindsight it's not surprising that the t-test, which just subtracts the two means and scales them by the pooled SD, gets a more precise answer than `lm()`, which does some fancy linear algebra (QR decomposition: see `lm.fit()`) to arrive at the same answer.)

Unfortunately, it's not easy to adjust the printing precision low enough to make the coefficient print as zero: even

```r
printCoefmat(coef(ss), digits = 1)
```

(a way to get just the summary table) still prints `-3e-14`.

A hack, using `zapsmall()` to round the coefficient values in such a way that coefficients that are small (in absolute value) **relative to the largest coefficient** get set to zero:

```r
ss$coefficients[, "Estimate"] <- zapsmall(ss$coefficients[, "Estimate"])
printCoefmat(coef(ss))
##                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
## (Intercept)          75.000     25.000       3  0.02401 *
## as.factor(dose)Low    0.000     35.355       0  1.00000
```

You could also do this upstream with the output of `lm()`, or by creating a wrapper function to use in place of `lm()`:

```r
zlm <- function(...) {
   m <- lm(...)
   m$coefficients <- zapsmall(m$coefficients)
   m
}
```

Unfortunately there's not really any nice way to make things behave this way universally; it's just too hard to know exactly when it's safe/desirable to round small values to zero ...